# Sharing a library between android and a PC application

Tags: java, android, opengl, opengl-es

I'm trying to design a side scroller for android and a level editor for windows. A lot of the code between the two programs will be the same. The bit I'm currently working on is drawing textures.

What I currently have is a library that includes code related to loading and drawing the texture information. The bit that I'm stuck on is how would I incorporate OpenGL (for windows) and OpenGL ES (for android) into the library?

I thought about having an interface that includes all the drawing functions and then implementing that interface separately within each program (since one will use OpenGL and one OpenGL ES) but that still produces a lot of duplicated code (and kinda defeats the purpose of trying to create this shared library).

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Am I just over complicating this by trying to make it too flexible? I have been thinking about this for a few sdays now, so any input would be greatly appreciated!

Please ask if anything doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL and OpenGL-ES are similar enough, that you can share large amounts of the codebase. Since you're probably going to target OpenGL-ES-2, you will then probably use OpenGL-3 on the desktop. OpenGL-3 has a lot of what OpenGL-ES-2 has. So I suggest you develop your code primarily for OpenGL-ES-2 and then only for the small differences toward OpenGL-3 you add alternative codepaths.